# Deriving NEC wire reactance table values

Tags: transmission-line

I'm verifying the NEC impedance table manually (how it gets the values in the table).

In the NEC list for AWG 1 above, the inductive reactance (Xl) for 1000 feet has value of 0.046 ohm for PVC conduit
See:
ftp://ftp.conagua.gob.mx/OCPBC/aps/Proyecto-PTAR-Las-Arenitas-Mxli,-B.C/MEMORIAS/6.-%20MEMORIA%20ELECTRICA/Tabla%209%20Resistencia%20y%20Reactancia%20de%20cables%20NEC%202008.pdf

1000 feet of awg 1 has calculated inductance of 687000 nH or 0.000687 H see: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/wire-self-inductance-calculator/

The inductive reactance is 2 pi f L... or 2 (3.141) (60) (0.000687) = 0.259 ohm see: www.66pacific.com/calculators/inductive-reactance-calculator.aspx

Why is the 0.259 ohm so far from the NEC listed value of 0.046 ohm?

How does NEC derive the 0.046ohm? Can you help derive 0.046 ohm? I've been trying it out for  hours already but couldn't match them. Thank you.

Comment: For one thing, the allaboutcircuits calculator is for a single isolated wire, while the NEC Table 9 is for three conductors in a conduit. Furthermore the NEC table refers to "Ohms to Neutral", which may imply that they're counting the effects of at least two conductors together.

Comment: I have actually used 3 conductors. But the inductive reactance is much higher at 0.852 ohm. Much greater than single conductor of 0.259 ohm compared to the listed 0.046 ohm which is just too low. How is the 0.046 ohm derived?  in the 3 conductors, one just uses 3000 feet instead of 1000 feet right?

Comment: You cannot use that calculator for integrated cable loop inductance calculations. Go looking for inductance per metre information for specific cable dimensions. There are calculators that will give a similar result I'm sure.

Comment: The 3 conductors are not shorted together. Can the cable inductance or even them inside a conduit change the inductance? Isn't it inductance are only properties of the wire? Or maybe the magnetic field can affect each other?

Comment: Inductance is not a wire-property but how the wire is shaped and how it might interact with other conducting objects placed locally especially the locally placed return conductor.

Comment: Even though the individual strands are not coated, I believe the stranding makes a difference beyond the effect of the diameter of the bundle of wires being greater than the equivalent solid wire diameter. For power frequencies that may be difficult to verify, but I suspect that is what you need to look for.